Como guardo un arraylist en un fichero que se encuentra en un paquete dentro del proyecto en netbeans 18?
Tengo este código en el cual los métodos de cargar me funcionan correctamente, pero cuando uso los de guardar, me saltan las excepciones de dichos métodos, diciendo que no se ha encontrado la ruta especificada.
Le puse el / delante a la ruta "data/Audiovisuales.dat" y seguía dándome el mismo problema.
public ArrayList<Audiovisual> cargarFichero() {
    ArrayList<Audiovisual> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try (ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/Audiovisuales.dat"))) {
        lista = (ArrayList<Audiovisual>) entrada.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al cargar el ArrayList: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return lista;
}

public ArrayList<Audiovisual> cargarEstreno() {
    ArrayList<Audiovisual> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try (ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/Estrenos.dat"))) {
        lista = (ArrayList<Audiovisual>) entrada.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al cargar el ArrayList: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return lista;
}

public void guardarFichero() {
    try (ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/Audiovisuales.dat"))) {
        salida.writeObject(visuales);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al guardar el ArrayList: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void guardarEstreno() {
    try (ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/Estrenos.dat"))) {
        salida.writeObject(estrenos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al guardar el ArrayList: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}



Perdón por los errores en la formulación de la pregunta es mi primera vez

Hola Javico, bienvenido, en algunas cosas, Java te pide las direcciones como "data/archivo.xxx", en otras "/data/archivos.xxx", en tu caso, creo que debes usar "src/data/archivo.xxx", sino, tambien puedes probar "/src/data/archivo.xxx".

La mejor práctica es crear un directorio llamado resources dentro del cual pongas tus carpetas/archivos. Imaginemos que dentro de resources  tienes el directorio data y dentro de ese directorio tienes el archivo archivo.txt, sólo harías esto: getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data/archivo.txt"). Así debería encontrar el archivo y no sólo en tiempo de depuración, sino también cuando el programa sea distribuido en un .jar ejecutable o de otro modo. El problema es que si no manejas adecuadamente los recursos, funcionaría en desarrollo, pero no en producción.
